# How can I make a Stack of images in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I saw a lot posts about how to do a text into a picture, I tried it and the 2 pictures were like this:
[images in flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mViys.png)

but I want it like this:
[how the images in flutter should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpEVE.png)

Can someone post an example?

EDIT: I changed the question and didn't knew about this Widget before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `Stack` widget. It takes a list of widgets as `children` parameter, being the first one in the back of the stack and the last one in the front.
Set `alignment` parameter as `Alignment.center` to obtain the centered result you're looking for.

```
Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  children: [
    Image(...), // Back image
    Image(...), // Front image
  ],
),
```

Comment: Thank you! Thats exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1):

you should use `Stack` its a `Widget`

widget of the week => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=liEGSeD3Zt8

api docs => https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html